# Associationg vim syntax with file extension

Tags: vim, syntax, file-type

how do I tell vim to use a certain syntax definition with a new file extension ? 
Let's say I have files that are some kind of xml, but have a different extension, how do I let vim know that it should use syntax=xml by default for that new type ?

Any help appreciated.