# Enable syntax highlighting for various filetypes in vim

Tags: vim

I can enable syntax highlighting for a file that has an extension that is unknown to vim by doing the following

> set syntax=c

Every time I switch tabs however, I have to renter the command. Is there any way to let vim know that a file with an extension `.xyz` should be coloured with C syntax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With autocommand. E.g.

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.xyz setf c
```

Comment: in case you get `E319: Sorry`, you may not have `vim` installed (even if it looks like you does)

Answer (score 26):

Put this at the end of your `.vimrc` (I'm assuming you have autocommands enabled).

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.xmlx set filetype=xml
```

Comment: Hmm... how is this answer answered on December 8, 2009 when the question was asked March 25, 2011? +1 nonetheless...

Comment: Whoa, very weird... I think this must be an SO bug. This answer must have been for another question, otherwise I wouldn't have mentioned XML.

Comment: @Samaursa This question was merged from http://stackoverflow.com/q/1869777/427545

Comment: I don't recommend using BufEnter.  That's triggered whenever focus enters the buffer.  As a result, Vim will re-parse the file every time you switch to it.  For some syntaxes and files, this can be quite slow.

Comment: @JustinL. thanks for the tip--BufRead seems to be a better idea.

Answer (score 20):

In your home directory, create the `.vim/ftdetect/xyz.vim`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz set filetype=c    " to overrule an existing filetype
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz setfiletype c     " to set it only if no filetype has been detected for this extension
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way to do it, instead of overloading your `~/.vimrc` file

Comment: My vim version (version 7.3.429) does not like the comment part. Removing the comment including the ';' works great. Thanks

Comment: Updated to use vi comment char instead ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can set it in the vim config file:

http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers