# In vim, why my autocmd setfiletype command not working?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I add this,

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown setfiletype octopress
```

But it seems not working because after I open a xxx.markdown file and input the command `setfiletype octopress` everything works fine.

Here is my intact .vimrc

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype off
colorscheme desert
set nu
set mouse=a
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
filetype plugin indent on    

Bundle 'vim-octopress'
autocmd FileType markdown setfiletype octopress
```

Hope someone can help me and tell me how to debug this thing...

Comment: Your question is very narrow. The general question is already answered in [Enable syntax highlighting for various filetypes in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437471/enable-syntax-highlighting-for-various-filetypes-in-vim)

Comment: Probably not the problem but You have `set nocompatible` multiple times in the file. You should remove the duplicates and place it as the first line in the file so you do not undo things you have already set (Edit: Actually you have lots of stuff thats duplicated...)

Comment: @Lstor I know the way to set syntax, but my autocmd just not working, I want to know why and how to debug it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the line itself. Try removing other parts of your `.vimrc` until it starts working, or possibly troubleshoot other parts (like paths). This is really not a constructive question.

Comment: OK. I solve it. It's because `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz setfiletype c ; to set it only if no filetype has been detected for this extension` which is in one answer of the quesion that you mentioned. @Lstor Thank you for your criticism. This site become useful because of you guys.

Comment: @jeswang I rolled back your edits to the question. In the future you don't want to edit the meaning after you get a correct answer - it makes it harder for other people to find the question and answer later and ruins the context for the answer.

Comment: @Mike OK.I got that. What I wan to do is to short my vimrc to make the question more clearly.

Comment: @jeswang That's a good idea - I'd say go for it as long as the answer still makes sense. =)

Comment: @Mike Tested it and it's also rising the problem. Thank you for reminding that my first time editing is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown setfiletype octopress
```

I only see this at the end:

```
autocmd FileType markdown setfiletype octopress
```

I think fixing that will fix you issue.

**Update:**

A couple more things to consider.  First, the Markdown-syntax plugin sets the filetype to be `mkd`, not `markdown`.  This doesn't seem to work correctly either:

```
autocmd FileType mkd setfiletype octopress
```

But this does:

```
au FileType mkd set filetype=octopress
```

...And that makes sense now.  `setfiletype` won't set the file type if it's [already been set](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%3asetfiletype).  Since it was already flagged as being of type `mkd`, it wasn't being updated to the new file type.

Comment: Is the filetype being set correctly with the first version?  I setup a vimrc with only `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown setfiletype octopress` in it, and then ran `vim -u ./my-vimrc -U NONE xxx.markdown`.  Typing `:set filetype?` showed that it was properly set to octopress.

Comment: I know it works. I guess it's something in the .vimrc makes this command not working.

Comment: Step one is to verify that the filetype is being set correctly with your `autocmd`.  I know it works when you say `setfiletype octopress` manually, but does the file have the correct file type without doing that?  I don't think it is.

Comment: What's going on. I change `setfiletype octopress` to `set filetype=octopress` and it works well. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `setfiletype ... but only if not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands.`

[Doc about setfiletype function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%3asetfiletype)

Comment: You can use both: `set filetype` and `setfiletype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
au FileType htm,html,php,css setl ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 et
```