# Define new syntax color in vim without access to $VIMRUNTIME

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have no access to the $VIMRUNTIME directory,only the root can, I am just a user.

Is there a way in the .vimrc to link the extension xyz to the color syntax file xyz.vim without putting it in the $VIMRUNTIME ?

Thanks

the solution pointed out does not work on my hand 
when i put my `xyz.vim` (hand-made) in the directory `.vim/ftdetect/`
and then

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz set filetype=xyz  
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz setfiletype xyz
```

the syntax color are not loaded. but If I try

```
 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz set filetype=c  
 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xyz setfiletype c
```

The C color syntax is loaded. On my case I want to loaded my hand-made colors contained in `xyz.vim`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable syntax highlighting for various filetypes in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437471/enable-syntax-highlighting-for-various-filetypes-in-vim)

Comment: The solution you pointed does not work on my side :(

Comment: Could you show us what you have in that `xyz.vim` file?